# How to set custom ratingbar for different screens in android

Tags: android, android-styles, ratingbar

Xml file:

```
<RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/row_item_rbRatingAvg"
   style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:isIndicator="true" />
```

Style file:

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
         <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/rating_bar_height</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/rating_bar_height</item>

    </style>
```

ratingstars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_icon_a" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_icon_a" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_icon" />
</layer-list>
```

dimens.xml

```
 <dimen name="rating_bar_height">38px</dimen>
```

above files i used for set my custom ratingbar. i have also different size images for star_icon_a and star_icon. but still not working. in some devices, image get scaled and in some device image get cut. i dont know how to make for all screen sizes.

below is sample of drawable-xxhdpi size.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Define "defferent screens" please (dpi, sizes?). What is "not working"?

Comment: i dont know which part is not working. but i think it always take small size of image (hdpi) where screen device is (xhdpi,xxhdpi).

Comment: <dimen name="rating_bar_height">38dpi</dimen>
If you want application for different devices, never use px.